# Which philosophy views "value" as the god?

Tags: theology, terminology, philosophy-of-religion

What spiritual philosophy does Robert Lawrence Kuhn describe [here](https://www.closertotruth.com/interviews/2184)? This view says that everything exists because of the value of the totality of universe.

Comment: Not watched it, but he might be expanding on Thomas Persig's ideas in 'Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance'. A somewhat weird idea but some folks like it.

Comment: @PeterJ Hmm, that would be [Robert M. Pirsig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_M._Pirsig). ;-)

Comment: Oops. Pardon me.

Comment: Ferengi? Joking of course, but I have been watching a lot of Star Trek lately and there is an enormous amount of philosophy interwoven in the alien cultures of that show. I have found a reborn love of the Vulcan philosophy in particular. Some say it is like the Stoics.